# Node.JS / Upload file in Gorgias API

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data

My company started using Gorgias (a helpdesk service) and i am trying to upload a file using its API (https://developers.gorgias.com/reference/post_api-upload)

```
export const uploadFileFromBase64 = async (): Promise<any> => {
  const filePath = '/Users/rafaelpolonio/Documents/51c1076a502ed528e6696c72b5fecfef-silhueta-de-transporte-de-skate.png';

  if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
    console.log('File exists.');

    fs.access(filePath, fs.constants.R_OK, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('File is not readable:', err);
      } else {
        console.log('File is readable.');
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('File does not exist.');
  }
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append('file', fs.createReadStream('/Users/rafaelpolonio/Documents/51c1076a502ed528e6696c72b5fecfef-silhueta-de-transporte-de-skate.png'));
  console.log(form.getHeaders())

  const response = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://my-company.gorgias.com/api/upload?type=attachment',
      data: form,
      headers: { 
        'Authorization': 'Basic XXXX==', 
        ...form.getHeaders()
      },
  });
  console.log(response.data)
  return response.data
}
```

I added a code to verify if the file is accessible (and it is), but everytime i run the function, it returns 201, but with no data, what means that i didnt add any file to upload

It uses form data, so maybe i am doing something wrong
Can somebody help?

Comment: The API docs you linked pretty clearly state that the body field should be named `file` so why are you using `attachment`?

Comment: it doesnt matter.. it does not work with "file" or any other stuff ... in postman i can put random word and it will work

Comment: Just checking, are you using the [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) library or native [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)?

Comment: And which version of Axios are you using?

Comment: @Phil dude, thanks! i just updated axios to latest and it worked!

Comment: Which version did you have that wasn't working?